# if loop failing not if clause in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code for PHP

```
if ($checkimghash != $imghash)
{

the $checkimghash is var_dumped as this array(2) { [0]=> string(40) "da77c24758c6259274bfa171a32d5c4a4a2cb71c" ["PdfHash"]=> string(40) "da77c24758c6259274bfa171a32d5c4a4a2cb71c", the variable $imghash var_dumps as this
string(40) "da77c24758c6259274bfa171a32d5c4a4a2cb71c,
```

Why is this check running despite the equal results? I thought != needs to pass both type and value checks

Comment: Can you edit your var_dump results? It is unclear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are comparing an array to a string and they are not the same

try changing your test to

```
if ($checkimghash[0] != $imghash)
```

Answer (score 0):

!= is value, !== is value and type

Comment: This means nothing in this context.

Answer (score 0):

`!=` is only comparing the value. It's opposite is `==`

> **TRUE** if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.

`!==` is comparing both the value and the type. It's opposite is `===`

> **TRUE** if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

**Edit**

The `var_dump` result in your question is unclear. If you are comparing an array with a string, then they are always different. You may want to compare the value of an element of an array with another string by `$array[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Because if `$checkimghash` is an array and `$imghash` a string then the two won't directly compare (in any meaningful sense), as you're comparing an array (i.e. a collection of strings) to a string! select the element of the array you'd like to compare and use that in the condition.